# What type of bicycle frame is this?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

[image: bike frame]

Need help with identification. If anyone knows what kind of bike has the rear fender built in to the frame, that might help.

Comment: I've seen it before, but not for 30-40 years.

Comment: Ashtabula crank, big slotted dropouts and smaller size make me think it's a 'novelty' child's bike

Answer (score 3):

What pieces I can deduce from the looks of it.

1. It was designed for a single speed drivetrain.
2. No mounts for rim or disk brakes means it was likely meant for a drum rear brake
3. Ashtabula cranks mean it was old and/or cheap bike.
4. A curiously shaped "integrated" rear fender means the bike was unlikely to be designed to take part in competitions. Most likely it was a cruiser/utility/novelty bike.
5. Judging from relative diameters of head and seat tubes, it likely took a 1 inch fork, but it is hard to tell.
6. Wheel size as well as frame size are unclear as no reference measurements are provided. I can guess it was designed for wheels from 20" to 26".

Comment: I think this bike is strange enough that even an idea about the the reason for the frame style and vague idea about when it was made could be enough.

Answer (score 3):

This is an unusual but not unique frame shape for a kid’s bike. An example is the Kent Giggles bike shown below.

There’s a better picture at this link: https://www.varagesale.com/i/mzk6ev78-reduced-price-like-new-kent-cycling-brand-girls-14-bike-has-giggle-monkey-peace-sign-etc-design
 I have seen this design on other models as well.[image]